# How to edit or update SHA1 key of configuration file for google sign in

Tags: android, oauth

**How do I delete multiple SHA1 key which are not required for my android Google Sign-In project?**

I have an android project that implements Google Sign In feature for which I registered my SHA1 Key to generate a configuration file. Unfortunately, I had to format my laptop and then my SHA1 key changed resulting in requirement to change SHA1 key fingerprint to generate a configuration file for my project. After adding new SHA1 key I found there are two OAuth 2.0 client IDs so Now I don't have knowledge of deleting the old Id.

*After some research I figured out there is a manage credentials options*

I also tried to manage credentials and deleted the older client id but it just shows up again and again even if I delete it from OAuth Client IDs registered for my project.

**What should I Do to permanently delete other older Oauth client Ids?** 
[image of multiple SHA1 key being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNb2D.jpg)